# .3ds file import into Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend, 3dsmax

I have a .3ds file that I want to import into the 3D Viewbox in Silverlight.

I am currently using Expression Blend.

Is this possible? And if so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need it as .Obj format.

> Expression Blend can import 3D content in the .obj file format. For
>   these files to render correctly, you must also import the material
>   file (.mtl file) that defines the materials used on the 3D object, and
>   import all of the image files that are used in the material file.

If you need a free tool to convert in try Blender or Meshlab.

Comment: It would be nice if you could mark the answer as accepted, so that people see that a solution has been posted.